# the layer below the texture is visible

Tags: texturing, obj

I have imported an obj object from Boxshot. Everything is fine except it looks like the texture is a bit transparent. You can see it on the attached image. It looks like a small reflection, but it's not. As if you can see a bit of the underlying layer. It doesn't look like that in the Boxshot file itself, but only when I import the object into Blender. Do any of you know what the problem might be?
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share one of the objects that have the problem? don't forget to pack the image (File > External Data > Pack Resources): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi @moonboots. The project can be downloaded here: https://we.tl/t-zd92qJssj1
Thanks
Mikkel

Comment: @moonboots Thanks. can you recommend a tutorial thats shows how to merge it object by object?

Comment: I've given an answer, maybe there's an easier way to fix the problem, or simply ask for a clean file to the person who did it?

Answer (score 3):

You have a lot of overlapping faces, it creates these artefacts. Merging by distance won't fix the problem because it will mess up your UV. Maybe there's another way but it looks like you can simply select the correct parts with <kbd>L</kbd>, move them (or separate them as new object, etc), and remove the bad parts:

[image]